# Using grails plugin classes in a groovy project?

Tags: grails, groovy

Is it possible to use the classes from a grails binary plugin as a regular dependency in a groovy project?

After many different approaches the answer seems to be NO, but I feel like there is just a missing little piece dealing with dependencies.

### Using:

- sample-grails(grails 2.3.7) : Binary grails plugin with one dummy
  domain
- sample-groovy(groovy 2.2.1) : Groovy project that justs
  prints 'Hi' and regular dependency on
  'sample-grails-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'

### Problems:

1. If you dont add anything it does not compile:

   NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/dirty/checking/DirtyCheckable.
2. Add dependency "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.0.0.RELEASE"

   NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersDomainBindingApi;
3. Add dependency "org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.3.7"

   Compiles ok

   In runtime crashes:

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletResponse
       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersDomainBindingApi.getDomainClass(ControllersDomainBindingApi.java:97)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersDomainBindingApi.initialize(ControllersDomainBindingApi.java:58)
       at com.nortia.sample.Other.(Other.groovy)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
       at Library.main(Library.groovy:7)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletResponse
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
       ... 13 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a binary plugin is not the best approach as binary plugins really need a Grails environment. You can however create a binary plugin just using Gradle. The Cloud Foundry team do this, all you need to do is create your plugin class. Example:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration/blob/master/auto-reconfiguration/src/main/groovy/org/cloudfoundry/reconfiguration/grails/JavaBuildpackAutoReconfigurationGrailsPlugin.groovy

And then create a `META-INF/grails-plugin.xml` file pointing to the class. Example:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration/blob/master/auto-reconfiguration/src/main/resources/META-INF/grails-plugin.xml

You can then just use Gradle's standard `groovy` plugin to build your project.

If you want to create GORM entities then you need to add a dependency on the GORM jars. Example:

```
 compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE"
```

Then annotate each GORM entity with `grails.persistence.Entity`. Example:

```
 import grails.persistence.*

 @Entity
 class Foo { 
    String bar 
 }
```

Then modify your `grails-plugin.xml` file to point at the entity. Example:

```
    <plugin name='myplugin' version='0.1' grailsVersion='2.4 &gt; *'>
      <author>Your name</author>
      <title>My Plugin</title>
      <type>foo.bar.MyGrailsPlugin</type>
      <resources>
        <resource>mybin.Foo</resource>
      </resources>
    </plugin>
```